# How do I write a Unix script which counts the number of reviews in a file?

Tags: bash, file, unix

I have a number of files which each contain reviews of a hotel and I would like to write a script which counts the number of reviews per file. An example of one file name would be `hotel_73757`. The text in each file is laid out as follows:

```
<Overall Rating>3.5
<Avg. Price>$260
<URL>http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g31310-d73757-r23009196-Wyndham_Phoenix-Phoenix_Arizona.html

<Author>TexasSharvi
<Content>the new updo is ... it's great! 
<Date>Dec 26, 2008
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>4
<Value>4
<Rooms>4
<Location>4
<Cleanliness>5
<Check in / front desk>5
<Service>-1
<Business service>4

<Author>ChrisLongo
<Content>Just Dirty... Will never stay at any Wyndham hotel again. 
<Date>Dec 24, 2008
<No. Reader>1
<No. Helpful>1
<Overall>1
<Value>1
<Rooms>1
<Location>1
<Cleanliness>1
<Check in / front desk>1
<Service>1
<Business service>-1
```

This then repeats with a single line gap between each review, every review has the same fields. I was thinking of checking the number of times "Author" appears in each file would this work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
grep -c "Author" yourFile
```

If you really want to make a script of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# countreviews.sh
# Counts the number of times the word "<Author>" appears in the specified file.
################################################################################
grep -c "^<Author>" "$1"
```

Make it executable with:

```
chmod +x countreviews.sh
```

And run it with:

```
./countreviews.sh file
```

or

```
./countreviews.sh "file with space in name"
```

Comment: Thanks, does this take an argument of the file name as commented above?

Comment: You would replace `yourFile` with the name of the file you want the number of reviews from, or `"$1"` to put this in a script and examine the script's first command-line argument.

Comment: I replaced yourFile with "$1" but now I get the error "-bash: fg: %: no such job" when I type "% ./countreviews.sh hotel_224835.dat" into the command line

Comment: Thankyou so much, lastly the spec requires me to have % in front of the ./... line but when I do this it says -bash: fg: %: no such job?

Comment: The percent is probably just the prompt which is output by the computer, not input by you. You can't really add that to the script.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `grep` and `wc` to get the number of lines containing the word 'Author' appear in the file:

```
grep Author fileName | wc -l
```

grep will filter only the Author lines, wc -l will count them

Comment: Thank you, how would I write it so that it takes a file in the command line and counts the number of reviews? for example % ./countreviews.sh hotel_72572.dat.

Comment: it depends on the shell you are using, but usually it is $1