# Print out a statement before each output of my script

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have a script that checks each file in a folder for the word "Author" and then prints out the number of times, one line per file, in order from highest to lowest. In total I have 825 files. An example output would be

```
53
22
17
```

I want to make it so that I print out something before each number on every line. This will be the following `hotel_$i` so the above example would now be:

```
hotel_1 53
hotel_2 22
hotel_3 17
```

I have tried doing this using a for loop in my shell script:

```
for i in {1..825}
do
    echo "hotel_$i"
    find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -wo "Author" {} | wc -l' \; | sort -nr
done
```

but this basically prints out `hotel_1`, then does the search and sort for all 825 files, then `hotel_2` repeats the search and sort and so on. How do I make it so that it prints before every output?

Comment: Do you always want to search for the same string in the same directory 825 times? This doesn't make much sense. Can you explain your use case more or show a more realistic example?

Comment: I can't help but notice that you ask many related questions, and I don't think the end result will be ideal; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416492/how-do-i-write-a-unix-script-which-counts-the-number-of-reviews-in-a-file), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418255/how-to-make-a-shell-script-take-an-argument-passed-in-the-command-line) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419722/how-to-make-my-shell-script-check-every-folder-in-a-directory-for-a-word-and-the).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command, which combines lines from different files:

```
paste <(printf 'hotel_%d\n' {1..825}) \
<(find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -wo "Author" {} | wc -l' \; | sort -nr)
```

(Just putting this on two lines for readability, can be a one-liner without the `\`.)

This combines `paste` with [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), making the output of a command look like a file (a named pipe) to `paste`.

The first command prints `hotel_1`, `hotel_2` etc. on a separate line each, and the second command is your `find` command.

For short input files, the output looks like this:

```
hotel_1 7
hotel_2 6
hotel_3 4
hotel_4 3
hotel_5 3
hotel_6 2
hotel_7 1
hotel_8 0
hotel_9 0
```